# angularjs: server route when ng-view is on page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there any way to have some links on the page feed the ng-view container while others load the page from the server?
See this fiddle for example: http://jsfiddle.net/terebentina/Wy7Ww/

html:

```
<div ng-app="test">
    <a href="/">tab1</a>
    <a href="/tab2">tab2</a>
    <a href="/logout">logout</a>
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

js:

```
angular.module('test', []).config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        template: 'tab1'
        ,controller: 'TabCtrl'
    })
    .when('/tab2', {
        template: 'tab2'
        ,controller: 'TabCtrl'
    });
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
})
.controller('TabCtrl', function() {});
```

Basically I want the logout link to go to server while the 2 tabs to feed the ng-view.
As you can see, I only defined the tab routes in angular and no 'otherwise' section but it still tries to load logout in the ng-view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the url for logout to

```
<a href="/logout" target="_self">logout</a>
```

This would stop angular route from intercepting the location change.